# Is there any way to interpolate colors when using a structure grid in VTK?

Tags: visual-c++, vtk

I want to make a color map on  **vtkstructuredgrid** and I need the colors to be interpolated between cells. The other option is using point data but when ever I use

```
structuredgrid->PointData()->SetScalars(Floatarray);
```

it says I cant have a pointer to a incomplete class type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach *should* work...

However, `PointData` is not a method, for the `vtkStructuredGrid` class: you should avoid `()`, and that's the reason for the error (*Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed*).

Moreover, `PointData` is protected, in the "standard" definition of `vtkStructuredGrid`, and you should derive the entire class to access it from your code.

Before trying that, by the way, can you try with

```
structuredgrid->GetPointData()->SetScalars(Floatarray);
```

?

It should work too (not sure about the parameter type passed to `SetScalar()`, BTW).

Comment: The array is actually of type **vtkUnsignedCharArray.** So it would be, `structuredgrid->GetPointData()->SetScalars(UnsignedCharArray);`  It seems that the `GetPointData()` remedy did not work. Another concern I have with **vtkStructuredGrid** is even if I access **PointData** can I even interpolate colors this way?